# Find a value and append to it in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk to search for a number string between 1 and 65535 and append an * to it.  Here is what I am trying:

```
awk '/[1-65535]+$/ {$0=$0"*"} 1' file
```

When I run the command, I do not see an asterisk added to the number string in the file.

After appending the asterisk to the value I want to prepend an asterisk to the value:

```
awk '/1-65535]\* +$/ [$0="*"$0} 1' file
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please you must include input example and expected output

Answer (score 1):

A regexp that matches 1-65535 would be something like:

```
[1-5]?[0-9]{4}|6[1-4][0-9]{3}|65[1-4][0-9]{2}|655[1-2][0-9]|6553[1-5]
```

Think about and play with that until you nail it down precisely if you really want to go the regexp route. If/when you post concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you figure out a better approach.

Comment: [1.65535]{1,5} is a hell of a lot easier

Comment: `[1.65535]{1,5}` means the characters 1,3,5,6 or . repeated 1 to 5 times. So `66666` and `.` (a single period) would both match while `20` would not - i.e. it's not remotely what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear (For example, whether or not there are negative numbers in the input text), I show a `gnu-awk` solution using `FPAT` for spliting by content

> cat file

```
1agauga 1 
65535 9gagayg aha hdhduhd6 65536
5
813 0 shshsi616agauga1
```

Run it,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^0-9]+|[0-9]+"}{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        if($i~/^[0-9]+$/ && $i>=1 && $i<=65535) $i=$i"*"
        printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?ORS:"")
    }
}' file
```

you get,

```
1*agauga 1* 
65535* 9*gagayg aha hdhduhd6* 65536
5*
813* 0 shshsi616*agauga1*
```

Answer (score 0):

Check every word separately and if it's a number and between 1-65535 append `*` to it:

```
$ cat foo
d foo 1 bar2 asd 100000 cash
ding dong 300 pork -5 this1
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^[0-9]+$/ && $i>0 && $i<65536) $i=$i "*"}1' foo
d foo 1* bar2 asd 100000 cash
ding dong 300* pork -5 this1
```